# or condition in findByUsername() in yii2 with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, yii2-advanced-app

How can i use `or condition` in yii2 advanced template with `mongoDB`:

what i want:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE (username = '$username' OR email = '$username');
```

How can i put this condition in following function:

```
public static function findByUsername($username)
{
  return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-query-builder.md#operator-format- will tell you

Answer (score 0):

I have solved like this:

```
public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        $con = array('$or' => array(array('username' => $username),array('email' => $username)));
        return static::findOne($con);
    }
```